# Shortcut for matrix division?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a $p$-by-$q$ matrix $(A)$ and want to use it to calculate a new $p$-by-$q$ matrix $(C)$ where all values in each column of $(A)$ are divided by a different scalar. I can create this behavior by creating another $p$-by-$q$ matrix $(B)$ that repeats my $q$ scalars $p$ times and then dividing $A$ by $B$.

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 6 & 12\\
4 & 9 & 16\\
6 & 12 & 20\\
8 & 15 & 24\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 3 & 4\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 4 & 5\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$C = \frac{A}{B}$$

This works fine but I'm wondering if there is some shortcut for going from $A$ to $C$ that is simpler than creating $B$ and dividing $A$ by $B$. Still new to linear algebra, so apologies for the simple question.

**Edit:** Answer implemented in R

```
# Original version
A <- matrix(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 9, 12, 15, 12, 16, 20, 24), ncol = 3)
B <- matrix(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), ncol = 3)
A / B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6

# Accepted answer
D <- matrix(c(1/2, 0, 0, 0, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, 1/4), ncol = 3)
A %*% D
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same as multiplying on the right by a diagonal matrix

$$D=\pmatrix{1/2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1/3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/4}$$

Comment: You should multiply on the right, not the left !

Answer (score 4):

Dividing by a matrix only makes sense when you are dividing by a square invertible matrix (this is analogous to not being able to divide numbers by $0$). It is however clear that when you write $A/B$ you mean the matrix obtained from $A$ by dividing each square in $A$ by the number in the corresponding square in $B$. This notation isn't standard and is best avoided.

Instead of doing such things simply multiply the matrix on the right with the appropriate $q \times q$ matrix (see Joshua Tilley's answer for the correct matrix.).